# Java Formatter issue

Tags: java, social-gaming

```
java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier 's'
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2487) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2423) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2enter code here792) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at com.aionemu.gameserver.utils.audit.GMService.onPlayerUnavailable(Unknown Source) ~[AL-Game.jar:na]
    at admincommands.GMMode.execute(GMMode.java]:73) ~[na:na]
```

while I was sending a command inside game, I am getting this error.

is that problem related with my config files or, completely with java ?

the entire code is :

```
package admincommands;

 import com.aionemu.gameserver.model.gameobjects.player.Player;
 import com.aionemu.gameserver.network.aion.serverpackets.SM_MOTION;
 import com.aionemu.gameserver.network.aion.serverpackets.SM_PLAYER_INFO;
 import com.aionemu.gameserver.utils.PacketSendUtility;
 import com.aionemu.gameserver.utils.audit.GMService;
 import com.aionemu.gameserver.utils.chathandlers.AdminCommand;

  */
 public class GMMode extends AdminCommand {

    public GMMode() {
        super("gm");
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Player admin, String... params) {
        if (admin.getAccessLevel() < 1) {
            PacketSendUtility.sendMessage(admin, "You cannot use this command.");
            return;
        }

        if (params.length != 1) {
            onFail(admin, null);
            return;
        }

        if (params[0].toLowerCase().equals("on")) {
            if (!admin.isGmMode()) {
                admin.setGmMode(true);
                admin.setWispable();

                GMService.getInstance().onPlayerLogin(admin); // put gm into
                // gmlist
                GMService.getInstance().onPlayerAvailable(admin); // send
                // available
                // message
                admin.clearKnownlist();
                PacketSendUtility.sendPacket(admin, new SM_PLAYER_INFO(admin, false));
                PacketSendUtility.sendPacket(admin, new SM_MOTION(admin.getObjectId(), admin.getMotions().getActiveMotions()));
                admin.updateKnownlist();
                PacketSendUtility.sendMessage(admin, "you are now Available and Wispable by players");

            }
        }
        if (params[0].equals("off")) {
            if (admin.isGmMode()) {
                admin.setGmMode(false);
                admin.setUnWispable();

                GMService.getInstance().onPlayerLogedOut(admin); // remove gm
                // into
                // gmlist
                GMService.getInstance().onPlayerUnavailable(admin); // send
                // unavailable
                // message
                admin.clearKnownlist();
                PacketSendUtility.sendPacket(admin, new SM_PLAYER_INFO(admin, false));
                PacketSendUtility.sendPacket(admin, new SM_MOTION(admin.getObjectId(), admin.getMotions().getActiveMotions()));
                admin.updateKnownlist();
                PacketSendUtility.sendMessage(admin, "you are now Unavailable and Unwispable by players");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFail(Player admin, String message) {
        String syntax = "syntax //gm <on|off>";
        PacketSendUtility.sendMessage(admin, syntax);
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code that cause this exception

Comment: What game? What config files? You have a format specifier `s` somewhere and there is no corresponding argument. That's all we can say here with the information you provided.

Comment: Can we have a look at the part of code that raises this exception please?

Comment: ... We have a [tag:social-gaming] tag?!?

Comment: A good rule of thumb is: generally, it's a problem with one's code, not with Java itself.

Comment: sorry for code editing in question, it didnt allow me to  add as a code template.
thanks in advance..

Comment: There should be the call of String.format() somewhere. Where? What are the arguments?

Comment: According to the stacktrace the exception comes from `GMService.getInstance().onPlayerUnavailable(admin);`. The code for this method is still missing. Do you have the code of this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception tells you that there is a `String.format` taking place with more format specifiers than values for formatting. So somewhere there is a call like

```
ret = String.format("name %s, surname %s", "Firstname");
```

According to the stacktrace this happens in class
`com.aionemu.gameserver.utils.audit.GMService` somewhere in method `onPlayerUnavailable` which is missing in your question.

A short Google-search brought up [a Git-project](https://github.com/ghostfur/Aion-Lightning-4.9-SRC/blob/master/AL-Game/src/com/aionemu/gameserver/utils/audit/GMService.java) where you can see the source of the culprit and there you can see a call of `String.format`:

```
Iterator<Player> iter = World.getInstance().getPlayersIterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    PacketSendUtility.sendBrightYellowMessageOnCenter(iter.next(), "Information : " + String.format(adminTag, player.getName()) + LanguageHandler.translate(CustomMessageId.ANNOUNCE_GM_DECONNECTION));
}
```

The variable `adminTag` is built in dependence of settings in the instance of `Player` you're passing, so to say more we'd need information about the state of that instance- Looking at the source in general only shows the following lines to be a possible reason for the exception you encounter:

```
if (MembershipConfig.PREMIUM_TAG_DISPLAY) {
    switch (player.getClientConnection().getAccount().getMembership()) {
        case 1:
        adminTag = sb.insert(0, MembershipConfig.TAG_PREMIUM.substring(0, 2)).toString();
        break;
    case 2:
        adminTag = sb.insert(0, MembershipConfig.TAG_VIP.substring(0, 2)).toString();
        break;
    }
}
// * = Wedding
if (player.isMarried()) {
    adminTag = sb.insert(0, WeddingsConfig.TAG_WEDDING.substring(0, 2)).toString();
}
```

Looking at the corresponding classes that hold the values for e.g. `TAG_WEDDING` I guess that your configuration contains customized values for at least one of these constants that start with `%s`, so that `adminTag` ends up as `%s%s`.

So to answer your question

> is that problem related with my config files or, completely with java ?

I guess that it's an error in your config file (some string starting with `%s`) or a bug in the library you're using but it's definitely not a bug in Java.

Comment: ahh, thank you. you are completely right. I have fixed it.

Comment: hi Lothar, can you please take a look my other question about the same emulator please. 
:  https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/162456/how-to-set-attack-range-of-a-weapon-type-in-an-aion-private-server